# Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, jls

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) states only **'write'** operation is treated as two parts:

> For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single **write** to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half.

But the book [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://jcip.net/) states **'read' or 'write'** operation is treated as two parts:

> the JVM is permitted to treat a 64-bit **read or write** as two separate 32-bit operations.

Which one is accurate?

Comment: There’s no contradiction: the first statement simply says nothing about reads at all. It does *not* say that reads can’t be split (though the absence of a mention of reads from the JLS is conspicuous).

Comment: @KonradRudolph If JLS does not say that reads can’t be split, then the 64-bit long can also be divided to three operations to read?

Comment: @Jason how read happens doesn't affect the behaviour of the program if the value doesn't change. If the value changes it can be in a non consistent state after the write, so the read will get an invalid value also if the read happens in one step.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO yeah, that is exactly what I am wondering: does 64-bit read happens in one step or not according to the JLS?

Comment: @Jason JLS doesn't explicitly say it. So both implementations (one or two reads) are valid.  What the JLS explicitly says is that you need to use volatile on long and double values if their value can change to be sure to have no inconsistent values

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Then all implementations (3 or 4... reads) are also valid? if so, then the states from 'Java Concurrency In Practice' is wrong?

Comment: @Jason I think this sentence in JLS implies read of non-volatile long/double may not be atomic  `Writes and reads of volatile long and double values are always atomic.`. And the sentence for non-volatile long/double -> `This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.` means it is either 1 or 2 reads and not more than that.

Comment: If write is done in two steps, what observable difference could there be if read is done in either one step vs. two? I can't think of any behaviour which could occur in one case but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

Digging through the past editions of the JVM spec, there is an [interesting section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/Threads.doc.html#22244) from Java SE 6:

> If a `double` or `long` variable is not declared `volatile`, then for the purposes of *load, store, read, and write* operations it is treated as if it were two variables of 32 bits each; wherever the rules require one of these operations, two such operations are performed, one for each 32-bit half. The manner in which the 64 bits of a `double` or `long` variable are encoded into two 32-bit quantities and the order of the operations on the halves of the variables are not defined by The Java Language Specification.
>
> This matters only because a *read or write* of a `double` or `long` variable may be handled by an actual main memory as two 32-bit read or write operations that may be separated in time, with other operations coming between them. Consequently, if two threads concurrently assign distinct values to the same shared non-`volatile` `double` or `long` variable, a subsequent use of that variable may obtain a value that is not equal to either of the assigned values, but rather some implementation-dependent mixture of the two values.
>
> An implementation is free to implement *load, store, read, and write* operations for `double` and `long` values as atomic 64-bit operations; in fact, this is strongly encouraged. The model divides them into 32-bit halves for the sake of currently popular microprocessors that fail to provide efficient atomic memory transactions on 64-bit quantities. It would have been simpler for the Java virtual machine to define all memory transactions on single variables as atomic; this more complex definition is a pragmatic concession to current hardware practice. In the future this concession may be eliminated. Meanwhile, programmers are cautioned to explicitly synchronize access to shared `double` and `long` variables.

This section is not present in later releases. I don't want to speculate on why (although it's worth noting that this section was adapted from the first edition of the JLS, while the memory model was revisited in Java 5), but this goes with what is described in JCIP.

Comment: Thanks for the digging, it is really interesting, I also found this part from the first edition of JLS(https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jls1-spec/). So does JCIP's states about 'long and double read' is outdated?

Comment: I checked it again, this section is still present in the second JLS edition(2000)(http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0.pdf). It is not present since the third JLS edition(2005)(http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/share/langspec-3.0.pdf).

Comment: @Jason I don't think the JCIP info is outdated. Maybe the "read" part is implicit or just irrelevant with regards to the memory model in the current JLS.

Comment: Also, JCIP seems based on the third edition of JLS, as following quoted from JCIP: `Where appropriate, we cross-reference relevant sections of The Java Programming Language, Concurrent Programming in Java, The Java Language Specification (Gosling et al., 2005), and Effective Java (Bloch, 2001) using the conventions [JPL n.m], [CPJ n.m], [JLS n.m], and [EJ Item n]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's both reads and writes. It can not be otherwise. Think about it, what if you code on `ARM` with `32 bits` (like a phone, for example). While a thread does a write to a `long`, a reader (unless you mark that `long` with `volatile`) is allowed to see a torn value. It happens simply because the architecture does not have a 64-bit register to update the value atomically.

On `x86` that is easily achieved, of course, since it has `64 bit` registers. But even there, a value can be "with one foot" on one cache line, and "with other foot" on another cache line. So when someone updates the first cache line (but not the second), you could be into a surprise. The `VM` as such aligns `64 bit` values onto a power of two off-set all the time (and a multiple of `8`). For example a `class` like:

```
static class Example {
    long x = 42;
}
```

is going to be aligned as:

```
 Layout$Example object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                              
     0    12        (object header)                           
    12     4        (alignment/padding gap)                  
    16     8        long Example.x
```

that is : there is a `4 bytes` gap (padding) between the headers and the actual value of `x` so that it is aligned. This makes sure that `x` is not going to end up on two cache lines.